# Why can't I show accents in Latex?

Tags: latex, utf-8

As soon as I use accents in my text, it won't work anymore. It reports the error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> R\UTF 
                 {00E9}seau Ethernet
l.88 \section{R\UTF{00E9}seau Ethernet}

?
```

To explain the output a bit, I am trying to compile `\section{Réseau Ethernet}` in that line.

I think it has to do with the encoding. Can somebody tell me where I should look into to fix this? I use TeXShop with MacOs X. Is there any additional information I should provide?

Edit: I think the actual problem seems to have to do with this warning:

```
Package frenchb.ldf Warning: The definition of \@makecaption has been changed,
(frenchb.ldf)                frenchb will NOT customize it;
(frenchb.ldf)                reported on input line 83.
```

Since I already use

```
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

Answer (score 7):

Have a look here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Internationalization.

Here is what I use with TeXlive, on GNU/Linux:

```
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

Your setup code may differ, e.g. with TeTeX I had to add `\usepackage{ucs}` and use `utf8x` instead of `utf8`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a [LaTeX cheatsheet](http://www.stdout.org/~winston/latex/latexsheet.pdf) [PDF warning].  The é character can be made using the \'e command.  I don't think you need to change the encoding.

Comment: Thank you. This actually does the trick for the moment, but I used to have it working using the accents.

Comment: I love Unicode as much as the next person but I think using the accents in this case would be more readable in terms of the TeX file.  Perhaps that doesn't really answer your question though.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding;

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

to the start of the document.

Answer (score 1):

From version [1.35 TexShop](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/SCRIPTs/page.php?site_id=nrsi&item_id=xetex_texshop) supports [XeTeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XeTeX), so say goodbye to LaTeX utf8 hell and write in whatever language and font you want.